# Does pointwise monotone convergence imply 2-norm convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on the segment $[0,1]$. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^{2}([0,1])$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$  p.w. and $f_{n+1}\geq f_{n}$. Does $f_n\rightarrow f$ also in the 2-norm? (what if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of simple functions?)

Comment: I'm surprised that you know what $L^2$ is without knowing the monotone convergence theorem. Where did you learn this material from? By the way, what does "p.w." mean?

Comment: p.w. = pointwise I guess

Comment: But the pointwise limit of $L^2$ functions need not be $L^2.$ Consider the family given by $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1/n}}.$ Then $f_n$ is a positive, nondecreasing sequence of $L^2([0,1])$ functions, but the pointwise limit ${1}/{\sqrt{x}}$ is not $L^2.$ Moreover, neither is $|f_n -f|$ for any $n.$ The monotone convergence theorem only answers the $L^1$ analog of mathfreaks question.

Answer (score 3):

This is what is called the [Monotone Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), and it is one of the most important convergence theorems for integration of functions and summation of series.

In your particular case, $f_n\to f$ pointwise and monotonically increasing, so $f_n-f\to 0$ pointwise and monotonically increasing.  This means that $|f_n-f|^2\to 0$ pointwise and  monotonically decreasing.  Thus, $\int_0^1|f_n(x)-f(x)|^2{\rm d}x\to 0$ by monotone convegence.  If you want to stick with monotonically increasing functions, $-|f_n-f|^2\to 0$ pointwise and monotonically increasing.

I just noticed that nowhere was it specified that $\|f_n\|_{L^2}$ was bounded.  If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^2}=\infty$, then $f\notin L^2$.

Comment: Further explanation: $|f_n-f|^2$ decreases to zero pointwise.

Comment: Why? It seems to me that the monotone convergence theorem assures that $f_n \to f$ in the $1$-norm. Why also in $2$-norm?

Comment: @GEdgar: sorry, I was working on that, but I was drawn away for a while.

Comment: Yes. But this only works if the pointwise limit is bounded.

Comment: @jspecter: I noticed that and appended my answer appropriately.

Comment: Monotone convergence requires both monotone increasingness and nonnegativity.

Comment: @Zarrax: I was using the version not requiring non-negativity, derived from the non-negative version:  Let $f^+(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}f(x)&\mathrm{if\ }f(x)\ge0\\0&\mathrm{if\ }f(x)<0\end{array}\right.$ and $f^-(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}0&\mathrm{if\ }f(x)\ge0\\-f(x)&\mathrm{if\ }f(x)<0\end{array}\right.$ Then $\{f_n^+\}$ and $\{f_0^--f_n^-\}$ are non-negative, non-decreasing sequences of functions tending to $f^+$ and $f_0^--f^-$ respectively.  Apply the non-negative restricted version to $f_n^++(f_0^--f_n^-)-f_0^-(=f_n)$ which converges to $f^++(f_0^--f^-)-f_0^-(=f)$

Comment: @Zarrax: the ideas of which are used in your answer, I see.

Comment: @robjohn so I guess another way of saying this is that in your answer you are applying the normal monotone convergence thm to $\int(|f|^2 - |f_n - f|^2)$ and then subtracting off $\int|f|^2$ from both sides.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the limit function $f$ is in $L^2$ this is true. Let $f_n^+$ and $f^+$ denote the positive parts of $f_n$ and $f$ respectively, and $f_n^-$ and $f^-$ the negative parts. Then by the monotonicity conditions you have
$$|f_n| \leq |f_n^+| + |f_n^-| \leq |f^+| + |f_1^-|$$
$$|f| \leq |f^+| + |f^-| \leq |f^+| + |f_1^-|$$
So if $g(x)$ denotes $|f^+| + |f_1^-|$, then $g(x)$ is an $L^2$ function that dominates $|f|$ and each $|f_n|$. Hence 
$$|f_n - f|^2 \leq (|f_n| + |f|)^2 \leq 4g^2$$
Since $4g^2$ is in $L^1$, the dominated convergence theorem gives 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n - f|^2 = 0$$
This is the desired $L^2$ convergence.